# How to wrap part of text with a <span> or any other HTML tag without new HTML structure being escaped?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am matching a specific string in an element text, and want to wrap the matching text with a span to be able to select it and apply modifications later on, but the html entities are being escaped. Is there a way to wrap the string with html tags with it being escaped ?

I tried using `unescapeEntities()​`, method but it doesn't work in this case.
`wrap()` didn't work as well.
for reference to those methods check https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html

Current code :

```
for (Element div : doc.select("div")) {
    for (String input : listOfStrings) {
        if (div.ownText().contains(input)) {
            div.text(div.ownText().replaceFirst(input, "<span class=\"select-me\">" + input + "</span>"));
        }
    }
}
```

Desired output

`<div>some text <span class="select-me">matched string</span></div>`

actual output

`<div>some text &lt;span class=&quot;select-me&quot;&gt;matched string&lt;/span&gt;</div>`

Comment: You don't want to use the `text()` method but instead add a new element with methods like `appendElement()` or `after()` (with the `Node` type argument).

Comment: okay, but how to append it in that specific location with the desired text ?

Comment: That depends on the original content. When you want to add it at the end of the text of the element, you can use methods like `appendElement() or `after()` depending on which `Element` object you call them. If the element should be inserted inside the string you need to split the text first in two text nodes and add the new `Element` in between them.

Comment: I want it to be wrapping that matched text not before it or after it.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that that your element (div) will contain only text, or can it also contain some inner elements like `<a>` or other `<span>`?

Comment: it can contain some inner elements

Comment: Can text you want to replace be placed in one of those inner elements?

Comment: no I want it is direct parent before the replacement to be a div tag

Comment: Just to be sure, if you have `<div> ab cd <span> cd ef</span><div>` then if you want to replace `cd` then only first one should be replaced but not second one because second one is inside inner element <span>?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question and comments it looks like you only want to modify direct text-nodes of selected element without modifying text node of potential inner elements of selected text so in case of

```
<div>a b <span>b c</span></div>
```

if we want to modify `b` we only modify one directly placed in `<div>` but not one in `<span>`.

```
<div>a b <span>b c</span></div> 
       ^       ^----don't modify because it is in <span>, not *directly* in <div>
       |
     modify
```

Text is not considered as `ElementNode` like `<div>` `<span>` etc, but in DOM it is represented as `TextNode` so if we have structure like `<div> a <span>b</span> c </div>` then its DOM representation would be

```
Element: <div>
├ Text: " a "
├ Element: <span>
│ └ Text: "b"
└ Text: " c "
```

If we want to *wrap* portion of some text into `<span>` (or any other tag) we are effectively splitting singe TextNode

```
├ Text: "foo bar baz"
```

into series of:

```
├ Text: "foo "
├ Element: <span>
│ └ Text: "bar"
└ Text: " baz"
```

To create solution which uses that idea [TextNode](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html) API gives us very limited set of tools, but among available methods we can use

- [`splitText(index)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#splitText-int-) which modifies original TextNode leaving "left" side of the split in it and returns new TextNode which holds remaining (right) side of the split like if `TextNode node1` holds `"foo bar"` after `TextNode node2 = node1.splitText(3);` `node1` will hold `"foo"` while `node2` will hold `" bar"` and will be placed as immediate sibling after `node1`
- [`wrap(htmlElement)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#wrap-java.lang.String-) (inherited from `Node` superclass) which wraps TextNode in ElementNode representing `htmlElement` for instance `node.wrap("<span class='myClass'>")` will result in `<span class='myClass>text from node</span>`.

With above "tools" we can create method like

```
static void wrapTextWithElement(TextNode textNode, String strToWrap, String wrapperHTML) {

    while (textNode.text().contains(strToWrap)) {
        // separates part before strToWrap
        // and returns node starting with text we want
        TextNode rightNodeFromSplit = textNode.splitText(textNode.text().indexOf(strToWrap));

        // if there is more text after searched string we need to
        // separate it and handle in next iteration
        if (rightNodeFromSplit.text().length() > strToWrap.length()) {
            textNode = rightNodeFromSplit.splitText(strToWrap.length());
            // after separating remining part rightNodeFromSplit holds
            // only part which we ware looking for so lets wrap it
            rightNodeFromSplit.wrap(wrapperHTML);
        } else { // here we know that node is holding only text to wrap
            rightNodeFromSplit.wrap(wrapperHTML);
            return;// since textNode didn't change but we already handled everything
        }
    }
}
```

which we can use like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div>b a b <span>b c</span> d b</div> ");
System.out.println("BEFORE CHANGES:");
System.out.println(doc);

Element id1 = doc.select("div").first();
for (TextNode textNode : id1.textNodes()) {
    wrapTextWithElement(textNode, "b", "<span class='x'>");
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("AFTER CHANGES");
System.out.println(doc);
```

Result:

```
BEFORE CHANGES:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   b a b 
   <span>b c</span> d b
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>

AFTER CHANGES
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <span class="x">b</span> a 
   <span class="x">b</span> 
   <span>b c</span> d 
   <span class="x">b</span>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Detailed explanation in the comments:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

public class StackOverflow56717248 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfStrings.add("INPUT");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(
                "<div id=\"1\">some text 1</div>" +
                "<div id=\"2\"> node before <b>xxx</b> this one contains INPUT text <b>xxx</b> node after</div>");
        System.out.println("BEFORE: ");
        System.out.println(doc);
        // iterating over all the divs
        for (Element div : doc.select("div")) {
            // and input texts
            for (String input : listOfStrings) {
                // to find the one with desired text
                if (div.ownText().contains(input)) {
                    // when found we have to be aware that this node may not be the only child
                    // so we have to iterate over children nodes
                    for (int i = 0; i < div.childNodeSize(); i++) {
                        Node child = div.childNode(i);
                        // taking into account only TextNodes
                        if (child instanceof TextNode && ((TextNode) child).text().contains(input)) {
                            TextNode textNode = ((TextNode) child);
                            // when found the one matching we can split text node
                            // into two nodes breaking it on position of desired text
                            // which will be inserted as a next sibling node
                            int indexOfInputText = textNode.text().indexOf(input);
                            textNode.splitText(indexOfInputText);
                            // getting the next node (the one newly created!)
                            TextNode nodeWithInput = (TextNode) textNode.nextSibling();
                            // we have to split it again in case there is more text after the input text
                            nodeWithInput.splitText(input.length());
                            // now this node contains only input text so we can wrap it with whatever you want
                            nodeWithInput.wrap("<span class=\"select-me\"></span>");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("RESULT:");
        System.out.println(doc);
    }

}
```